Module not found after creating from .conda file
I am working with an offline device, so I am trying to install packages via .conda files or .tar.bz2 files. In particular, I am trying to install python-levenshtein. I ran the following commands:
(myenv) C:\Users\my_user>conda install --offline "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\pkgs\python-levenshtein-0.26.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.conda
I placed the conda file within the packages directory in conda. Additionally, the package is also visible with conda list. However, when I try to run import Levenshtein from within python, I keep getting a module not found error. This happens for every package that I try to install via .conda or .tar.bz2. I place it within the relevant directory, everythings runs fine, it has the right install location in the package plan, and it's visible in the packages, but python can't use it. Why? Thanks.
